# Is Thomas-Fermi screening the result of a Thomas-Fermi model in an external field?

Tags: electrostatics, statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, many-body, density-functional-theory

On the one hand, the theory of **Thomas-Fermi screening** describes the response of an ideal metal (or electron gas) in the presence of an external field. In this theory, one assumes that you have a Fermi gas (number density $n\propto E_{\rm F}^{3/2}$, the Fermi energy) and the induced charge $\rho_{\rm ind}$ is proportional to the electrostatic potential $\phi(\mathbf r)$. The screening leads to the following expression for the dielectric function:
$$\epsilon(\mathbf k)=1+\frac{k_{\rm TF}^2}{k^2},$$
where $k_{\rm TF}$ is a constant and $\mathbf k$ is the wavevector in phase space.

On the other hand, **Thomas-Fermi model** is a model to approximate the electronic density of a system with free electrons in many-body systems and in density functional theory (DFT). It also assumes a Fermi gas ($n\propto E_{\rm F}^{3/2}$), a $\rho_{\rm ind}\propto \phi(\mathbf r)$ and leads to the following kinetic energy functional:
$$T[n]\propto\int n^{5/3} \mathrm d^3\mathbf r.$$

My question is: if I were to make a many-body calculation of the screening due to an external potential using the Thomas-Fermi model's $T[n]$, would I recover the Thomas-Fermi screening expression for $\epsilon$? My guess is yes, because the assumptions seem to be the same. I am just asking because they usually appear in separate sections of textbooks. Is there any specific difference in the predictions of the two with respect to the response of a metal/electron gas in the presence of a $\phi(\mathbf r)$?

Another way to rephrase the question would be to ask which is the DFT functional that results in Thomas-Fermi screening?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge Thomas-Fermi model was first developed for atoms - its application to solid state, particularly in terms of DFT are later developments. [Debye screening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_length) and [Thomas-Fermi screening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas%E2%80%93Fermi_screening) can be viewed as two opposite limits - one of high temperature (non-degenerate electron gas) and of lower temperature (degenerate electron gas.)

What might be confusing is that one often arrives to the expressions for screening length or dielectric permittivity not by using the original model, but by other methods, and also sometimes in generalized form - e.g., Thomas-Fermi can be viewed as a limit of [Lindhard theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindhard_theory), which is actually where the formula in the OP comes from (it is really Lindhard rather than TF result.) [Fetter&Walecka](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486428273), in my memory, go to great lengths deriving screening length diagrammatically, showing that they can get the classical result.

Comment: My question was more focused on the link between the two (screening and functional). From a second quantization point of view, both seems very similar, if you consider a gas of electrons with exchange interactions then you get Lindhard (RPA) screening which tends to Thomas-Fermi (TF) screening for long wavelenghts. From the point of view, of density functionals, Lindhard seems to be similar to TF functional+ a given exchange functional+external field. Another way to rephrase it would be to ask which is the functional results in TF screening.